# Persitence of information after clearing app data

Tags: android, sqlite

I store some of the information in shared preferences and some in sqlite database through my app.
Then I go to settings and clear data of my app. 
Where should the information persist after clearing the app data..shared preferences or sqlite database ?

Comment: Clearing an app's data removes both shared preferences and databases (and everything else in the app-specific data directory). What's the question, really?

Comment: Once you do the clear data of your application it will automatically remove all your sharedpreference's and database .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clear the app data from settings it will clear both shared preference and sqlite data. Application will behave as you new installed apl

Answer (score -1):

when you clear data both database and sharepreference get cleared...instead of this you can save data at multiple places..like shared preference,internal file system,external file system and make file hidden so that no one can forcefully delete it.

And when you need data...first check for shared preference then in both file system...sequentially..

Comment: All these places can be deleted.

Comment: when you delete or uninstall the app..i guess sdcard persist the data..and if i save the file in sdcard..and make it hidden..it will be there..untill user clears the sdcard.. @ CL.